# Vertically Align Individual Text Characters within a Word or Sentence

Tags: html, css, wordpress, alignment

I use a logo that is line and text based. I am wanting to include a variant of this in my website but create the logo from CSS.

[image]

I'm trying to get "T - S o N" as one line but with the "o" vertically centered between the "S" and "N", as in the logo above.

I'm very new to CSS and have struggled to get anything to work so far. I'm guessing that a table is the way to go but I dont really know how to go about it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @mbync. It's the easiest and better way to do this. If anyone still interested in how do to this in table way, here it is

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 25px;">
      <td>S</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: initial;">o</td>
      <td>N</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make sure the text stays on the same line no matter what, use this:

```
div#logo {
 white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will make your entire line of text one line and prevent it from dropping down to the next line when the text runs out of room in the div, the "overflow: hidden;" property will cause the text to disappear if it runs out of room rather than move outside the div.

If you want to vertically align the text use this:

```
div#logo {
line-height: 100px; /* play around with this value */
}
```

line height is my favorite way to vertically align text because it gives me complete control over it and it seems to cause the least amount of problems.